How to convert a AutoModelForCausalLM object to a dspy model object?

import dspy

llm = dspy.HFModel(model='model')


This method takes a string as input for the model if i have a quantized model object of the class AutoModelForCausalLM How i can convert the model object to dspy object?
direct assignment gives error on inference

llm = model #previously created as AutoModelForCausalLM class object

llm("Testing testing, is anyone out there?")


Error After Code Line 4
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py:623, in LlamaModel.forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, position_ids, past_key_values, inputs_embeds, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
621     raise ValueError("You cannot specify both decoder_input_ids and decoder_inputs_embeds at the same time")
622 elif input_ids is not None:
--> 623     batch_size, seq_length = input_ids.shape
624 elif inputs_embeds is not None:
625     batch_size, seq_length, _ = inputs_embeds.shape
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

I think i have missed the documentation details.
nit signature:
dspy.HFModel(
model: str,
checkpoint: Optional[str] = None,
is_client: bool = False,
hf_device_map: Literal['auto', 'balanced', 'balanced_low_0', 'sequential'] = 'auto',
token: Optional[str] = None,
model_kwargs: Optional[dict] = {},
)
Docstring: Abstract class for language models.
Init docstring:
Args:
model (str): HF model identifier to load and use
checkpoint (str, optional): load specific checkpoints of the model. Defaults to None.
is_client (bool, optional): whether to access models via client. Defaults to False.
hf_device_map (str, optional): HF config strategy to load the model.
Recommeded to use "auto", which will help loading large models using accelerate. Defaults to "auto".
model_kwargs (dict, optional): additional kwargs to pass to the model constructor. Defaults to empty dict.
File: /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dsp/modules/hf.py
Type: ABCMeta
Subclasses: HFClientTGI, HFClientVLLM, Together, Anyscale, ChatModuleClient, HFClientSGLang
So after reading this i have made following changes and the code work
import dspy
model_specific_param = {"torch_dtype": torch.float16,'quantization_config':bnb_config}
model_name = '/tmp/models/llama2/7b'
llm = dspy.HFModel(model=model_name,model_kwargs = model_specific_param)
